# Launch Java Program with weird thread dump

Tags: java, jvm, jstack

I have written a JavaFX program on Java 1.8 and it works well on my machine. However, when I deploy the program to another machine, the UI hangs and did not respond. So I use jstack commands to figure what's going on.

On my machine it works well and the dump log is like following:

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode):

"Worker-8" #46 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001b4cc800 nid=0x1f78 in Object.wait() [0x00000000292df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <0x00000000e0b00ea8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:51)

"Worker-6" #39 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d8dc000 nid=0x1e38 in Object.wait() [0x000000001cd1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <0x00000000e0b00ea8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:51)

"[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" #37 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d8db800 nid=0x1eec in Object.wait() [0x00000000279ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:106)
    - locked <0x00000000e32838b0> (a org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor)

"com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer" #35 daemon prio=1 os_prio=-2 tid=0x000000001d8d7000 nid=0x1430 in Object.wait() [0x0000000026e5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000e2a4d988> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer.run(Finalizer.java:114)

"Worker-4" #34 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d8da000 nid=0x4ac in Object.wait() [0x0000000020d8f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <0x00000000e0b00ea8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:51)

"org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" #32 daemon prio=1 os_prio=-2 tid=0x00000000163d5800 nid=0x1600 in Object.wait() [0x000000001e68f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:179)
    - locked <0x00000000e22a0a10> (a org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.DirtyRegionQueue)

"EventAdmin Async Event Dispatcher Thread" #31 daemon prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d8d7800 nid=0x1b50 in Object.wait() [0x000000001ce1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
    - locked <0x00000000e1a3a7d0> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"Java indexing" #29 daemon prio=4 os_prio=-1 tid=0x00000000163d6000 nid=0x1898 in Object.wait() [0x000000001cf1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.run(JobManager.java:382)
    - locked <0x00000000e1330ec0> (a org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Worker-1" #26 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000163d3000 nid=0x1254 in Object.wait() [0x000000001c0ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <0x00000000e0b00ea8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:51)

"Bundle File Closer" #25 daemon prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000163d2800 nid=0x978 in Object.wait() [0x000000001911f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
    - locked <0x00000000e139dfa8> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"EMF Reference Cleaner" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000163cf800 nid=0x12d4 in Object.wait() [0x000000001805f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000e0cda2d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.CommonUtil$1ReferenceClearingQueuePollingThread.run(CommonUtil.java:70)

"Worker-JM" #17 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000161bc000 nid=0x1280 in Object.wait() [0x0000000017e5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e0b4b878> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.InternalWorker.run(InternalWorker.java:59)
    - locked <0x00000000e0b4b878> (a java.util.ArrayList)

"[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000015dda800 nid=0x159c in Object.wait() [0x000000001815f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.timer.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:141)
    - locked <0x00000000e0cfb1f8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Start Level: Equinox Container: c021b39d-04a6-0014-1376-97e90e9c8ead" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000015c4b800 nid=0x1918 in Object.wait() [0x0000000017a5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e0a3bc80> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
    - locked <0x00000000e0a3bc80> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: c021b39d-04a6-0014-1376-97e90e9c8ead" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000162f7000 nid=0xe54 in Object.wait() [0x000000001795f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
    - locked <0x00000000e0ac4ae8> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"Active Thread: Equinox Container: c021b39d-04a6-0014-1376-97e90e9c8ead" #11 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001622f800 nid=0x12e4 waiting on condition [0x000000001759f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e0ac28e0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000014e06000 nid=0x1754 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000014ce0000 nid=0xd94 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000014cda000 nid=0x11b8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000014cd7800 nid=0x1ef4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001399a000 nid=0x1fdc runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000014ca3800 nid=0x1dd4 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x0000000013933000 nid=0x1b64 in Object.wait() [0x0000000014c8f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000e0170f20> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001392a000 nid=0x19dc in Object.wait() [0x0000000014b8f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000e0170f60> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000035f000 nid=0x1538 runnable [0x000000000012e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.WaitMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sleep(Display.java:4701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopIdle(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopIdle(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:918)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$3.eventLoopIdle(Workbench.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000013926000 nid=0x157c runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000021ed000 nid=0x17b4 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000021ee800 nid=0x1ce0 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000021f0000 nid=0xfc0 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000021f1800 nid=0x59c runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000014deb000 nid=0x94c waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 203
```

However, when I launch it on another machine, the dump log is totally different which is like :

```
2015-01-27 17:05:03
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode):

"Thread-6" #19 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000597c9800 nid=0x14f4 runnable [0x000000005dd0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at test.sd.PrTrSim.View.SimOverviewController$1.call(SimOverviewController.java:297)
    at test.sd.PrTrSim.View.SimOverviewController$1.call(SimOverviewController.java:1)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Prism Font Disposer" #18 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000059760800 nid=0x14b8 in Object.wait() [0x000000005c38f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c1fd4b68> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000c1fd4b68> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Thread-5" #17 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000059695000 nid=0x111c runnable [0x000000005aaae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000c2127a18> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at test.sd.PrTrSim.Connection.ServerSideSocketConnector.establishSocketConnection(ServerSideSocketConnector.java:16)
    at test.sd.PrTrSim.Connection.SocketConnector.run(SocketConnector.java:48)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Thread-4" #16 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000059694000 nid=0x1e1c waiting on condition [0x0000000059f9e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at test.sd.PrTrSim.Message.SimpleMessageProcessor.run(SimpleMessageProcessor.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"JavaFX-Launcher" #15 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000059224000 nid=0x1490 waiting on condition [0x000000005993e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c2128a58> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Thread-2" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000563d5000 nid=0x1238 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JavaFX Application Thread" #13 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000563c0800 nid=0x1a00 waiting on condition [0x00000000573dd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c1fb2410> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at test.sd.PrTrSim.View.SimOverviewController$1$1.run(SimOverviewController.java:303)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/814652983.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Thread-1" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000563b9000 nid=0x11a8 in Object.wait() [0x000000005755f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c207e9c8> (a java.lang.StringBuilder)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000c207e9c8> (a java.lang.StringBuilder)

"QuantumRenderer-0" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000056398800 nid=0x1258 waiting on condition [0x0000000055f0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c1fc16e0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000560a7800 nid=0xb1c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000054dbd000 nid=0x1b2c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000054dbc000 nid=0x1f84 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000056029800 nid=0x1e80 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000056027800 nid=0xc48 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000056027000 nid=0x1864 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x0000000054d53800 nid=0x17a8 in Object.wait() [0x000000005600f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c1e77e30> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000c1e77e30> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000054d4a800 nid=0x18d8 in Object.wait() [0x000000000252f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c1c09ee8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000c1c09ee8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000220f800 nid=0x17ec waiting on condition [0x000000000262d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c21285d8> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Unknown Source)
    at test.sd.PrTrSim.mainClass.main(mainClass.java:217)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000054d46800 nid=0x1958 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000207e000 nid=0x1e94 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000207f800 nid=0x18f8 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002081000 nid=0x1ecc runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002084800 nid=0x1bc8 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000560c3000 nid=0x1904 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 728
```

To the best of my knowledge, I found that the user name of the folder  hsperfdata_[myusername] does not match my machine and if I revise the name correctly, then the dump log will also be like the second sample.

Could any one help explain the tricks?

Comment: A difference is that a thread is busy in `at test.sd.PrTrSim.View.SimOverviewController$1.call(SimOverviewController.java:297)
    `  What does this method do?

Comment: take the head of a linked blocking queue at line 297. But it seems that the program should not hang.

Comment: I suggest you debug or profile your application to see what it is doing.

Comment: Thx, finally get it solved. The while true loop overload the thread, I made it sleep for 1s when no object found in the queue.